# How to extract QueryString value using NiFi processor/language expression?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am wondering how to extract a querystring value from incoming url using NiFi.
Initially, I started by implementing UpdateAttribute:

[image]

For example, I would like from the incoming url http://smth.net/hello?val=23
to have value of 23 extracted.

Further, I expect that I can use that extracted value by referencing it in following way:
(InvokeHttp processor) http://some.net/getValues?id=${q}

Any hints appreciated!

Edited question:

The flowfile inspect after extracting query string looks like:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use UpdateAttribute with [`replaceAll`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#replaceall) (regular expression):

```
${url:replaceAll('.*[\\?\\&]val=([^&]*).*','$1')}
```

maybe regexp could be optimized...

Comment: Thanks, in the following step (HttpInvoke) I use this value to create next request. How can I inspect in NiFi in easiest way what actual extracted value was used?

Comment: `Stop` the processor and check flow file attributes in the queue. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_nifi/apache_nifi_queues.htm

Comment: Thanks, Daggett. Though, for some reason - the querystring param is not passed into url. In the next request I have ?id= .. Empty for id's value.  Extract regex seems ok to me, and passing value in the request using ${q} also.

Comment: Extract regex seems ok , and passing value in the request using ${q} also. so i can't understand what's wrong... where do you see that query param is not passed? on server side?

Comment: in the regular expression, i've provided, there is a name of the parameter: `val=` seems you want to extract the parameter named `companyID=`. so just change the corresponding part of the regexp...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192959/discussion-between-neno-and-daggett).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the easiest possible way to retrieve a query string value is by using NiFi's expression like: ${http.query.param.[keyNameOfQueryString]}.. So, if the request URL is 127.0.0.1/hello?val=23 then the NiFi expression would be ${http.query.param.val}
[image: UpdateAttribute processor's Configuration]

Other way to do is using regex, as daggett suggested, but in my case I had to do the following:

```
${http.query.string:replaceAll('val=(\d+).*', '$1')}
```

Note http.query.string in place of url.